# react-navigation TabNavigator screen flex:1 show strange

Tags: react-native, flexbox, react-navigation, tabnavigator

when I use TabNavigator ,the flex:1 will show this,

```
<View style={{height: 100, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red', flex: 1}}>aaaaaa</Text>
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'green', flex: 1}}>bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb</Text>
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'blue', flex: 1}}>cccccccccc</Text>
```

[use TabNavigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AErCO.png)
[image]

when i do not use TabNavigator,the flex:1 will show this
[not use TabNavigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DzB3Q.png)
[image]